# Angular Web application SCORM package

Tags: angular, angularjs, scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2

I have an angular web porject and I wish to package it into a SCORM package so I could put it on any lms.

- How should I package it? Just place the files, link them in the manifest and thats it?
- Are there any other things I need to do other than using the SCORM api to make my project SCORM compatible?
- How running my project on an lms affects the communication with the database im using?

Would very appreciate any elaberation.

Thanks in advance, ODINN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- That can work. Preferably *all* files needed should be local and relative to an HTML file that would be the launch point.
- Generally, no. There are some things that have to be done as far as detecting the SCORM API, initializing, etc. A good reference can be found here: https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/
- This is a sticking point, if your UI application has to access a backend service or DB then it will need a way to connect to it, and unless all of your users have a way to get a credential dynamically through that front end then your application either would have no way to connect or you'd have to ship an authorization credential with it which is inherently insecure. A SCORM package is intended to only communicate through the SCORM runtime API so isn't intended to connect to 3rd party services.

Comment: Placing this in the comments rather than as an answer, but Rustici Cross Domain is a way to have remotely hosted applications that can still be launched as a SCORM package. See https://rusticisoftware.com/products/rustici-cross-domain/ for more.